# Mui Data Grid not updating certain columns with values fetched after fetching the main table

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, datagrid, mui-x-data-grid

I am populating a Mui Data Grid by a list that I'm fetching in useEffect. This returns a list such as `objects = [ { id: 'id', name: 'name', fieldA: '12345', fieldB: '12345' }, ... ]`. I simply just save this by `setObjects(objects)` in my state.

Then I use two fetches to get two lists where `fieldA` and `fieldB` are primary keys.

`A = [ { id: '12345', name: 'A1' }, ... ]` and B....

```
.then((res) => setA(A))
.then((res) => setB(B))
```

```
const [A, setA] = useState([]);
const [B, setB] = useState([]);
```

I am building my columns such as `fieldA` and `fieldB` are replaced by their names from the last two fetches.

```
const columns = [
...
{
  field: 'fieldA',
  headerName: 'Field A',
  width: 140,
  flex: 1,
  valueGetter: (params) => getNameById(params),
},
{
  field: 'fieldB',
  headerName: 'Field B',
  width: 140,
  flex: 1,
  valueGetter: (params) => getNameById(params),
},
...
]
```

`getNameById` should be called by both columns based on this

```
const getNameById = (params) => {
  const id = params?.row?.id;
  return A.find((a) => a?.id === id)?.name; // as example for A
};
```

But at this point A and B are both empty although the fetches are successful and I am fetching asynchronously and setting the state.

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async = () => {
    service.get('objects').then((res) => setObjects(res));
    service.get('A').then((res) => setA(res));
    service.get('B').then((res) => setB(res));
  })();
},[]);
```

Data Grid doesnt show anything in the cells.

**HOWEVER - If I use a hook to confirm that all fetches went through and conditionally render Data Grid, then the names are there...**

So basically `const [fetchedAll, setFetchedAll] = useState(false);`

```
useEffect(() => {
  (async = () => {
    service.get('objects').then((res) => setObjects(res));
    service.get('A').then((res) => setA(res));

    // FINALLY SET FETCHED ALL
    service.get('B').then((res) => setB(res)).finally(() => setFetchedAll(true));
  })();
},[]);
return(
 { fetched && <DataGrid rows={objects} columns={columns} /> }
);
```

Am I missing something? Why are A and B empty?

Thanks!